# Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError lopen failed: library name "/data/packagename/lib/arm64/libmobileffmpeg_abidetect.so" too long

Tags: android, ffmpeg

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError lopen failed: library name "/data/packagename/lib/arm64/libmobileffmpeg_abidetect.so" too long
```

I got this error in android 5 devices because my app packagename is too long. i build apk with abi filters `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`

```
 'java.lang.System.loadLibrary (System.java:989)
    com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.AbiDetect.<clinit> (AbiDetect.java)
    com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.AbiDetect.getNativeAbi (AbiDetect.java)
    com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.AbiDetect.setArmV7aNeonLoaded (AbiDetect.java)
    com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.Config.enableLogCallback (Config.java:5)'
```